# Itext7 - How to create pdf with 2 columns and 4 rows per page with images in java

Tags: itext7

I have following code to create a single pdf with 2 columns and 4 rows. Every cell contains an image.

```
int labelCount = x;
int columns = 2;
int labelsPerPage = 8;
int rows = labelCount/columns;
int resto = labelCount%columns;
if(resto>0) rows++;

String dest = "path_to_pdf_file";
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
doc.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

Table table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(columns)).useAllAvailableWidth();
Integer iCount = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    for (int y = 1; y <= columns; y++) {
        
        if(iCount<labelCount) {                 
            String fileName = "name_of_image";
            Cell cell = new Cell();
            cell.add(new com.itextpdf.layout.element.Image(ImageDataFactory.create("full_path_to_image")).setAutoScale(true));
            cell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            table.addCell(cell);
            iCount++;
            
            if(iCount==labelsPerPage-1) {
                doc.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
            }
        }
    }
}        

doc.add(table);
doc.close();
```

If number of labels is bigger than defined limit (8 per page), I want a new page to be created with the following labels.

In my code I used

```
doc.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
```

but it generate (I don't know why) a blank page at the beginning. In the second page there are labels.

Which is the right way to add a new page dynamically and put remaining content into it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Essentially in your code you add `AreaBreak` to the document before you add the table, that's why the blank page is inserted before the table. iText 7 does not allow you to insert page breaks within tables at this point.
To achieve the desired result you need to flush the existing table to the document before moving on to the next page, and create a new table for the next page. Essentially you will be adding a bunch of tables separated with `AreaBreak`.

The pseudocode which does not require a lot of modifications to your code could look as follows:

```
Table table = new Table();
for (...) {
    // populate table
    if ("it's time to insert a page break") {
        doc.add(table);
        doc.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
        table = new Table(); // create new table
    }
}
doc.add(table);
```